# NumberFormatException: Invalid int as a result of converting string containing binary digita to decimal

Tags: java, string, int, parseint

I have this problem where I have a Java string containing binary digits that is unable to be converted to the decimal equivalent.

The error in the question title is as a result of the below code :

```
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt("001001000110000111001001000111000110001010001011",2);
        System.out.println("Ciphertext :\t"+decimalValue);
```

However when i test with smaller strings of binary digit like "1101", the program runs fine. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Integers have a maximum value. I am guessing you are exceeding that value. It is merely a guess, though.

Comment: how would you suggest i proceed with BigInteger ?could you put a demo poc if it works i will mark yours as answer ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You're trying to parse more than 32-bits as an `int`. You need a long (based on your input) something like

```
long decimalValue = Long.parseLong(
        "001001000110000111001001000111000110001010001011", 2);
```

which is `40002404508299` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`).

Comment: `Integer.MAX_MAX_VALUE` is a typo I think.

Comment: @Gendarme Typo fixed. Thanks.